# returning a string as an integer java

Tags: java, string, integer

I am trying to return a string of names in a list as an integer, the names are pulled from a longer list.  i have managed to get the list of names needed but cannot figure out how to convert the string into an integer. see code below:

```
public static void doStuff(List<Seat> uk){
  for(Seat s:uk)
      if (s.place.contains("Edinburgh"))
          System.out.println(s.results);
```

This is where i get stuck does anyone have any advise on how to solve this?

Comment: If I have understood your question, do you want to convert String like `Edinburgh` to integer? How that would be possible? If not please add clarity.

Comment: do you mean the place "edinburgh" takes in the list? please calrify

Comment: Please check my answer. If you are looking at my solution, I think this is what you need.

Comment: the string i am trying to display as an integer looks like this:[Mandate@7852e922, Mandate@4e25154f, Mandate@70dea4e, Mandate@5c647e05, Mandate@33909752, Mandate@55f96302]
[Mandate@3d4eac69, Mandate@42a57993, Mandate@75b84c92, Mandate@6bc7c054, Mandate@232204a1, Mandate@4aa298b7, Mandate@7d4991ad, Mandate@28d93b30, Mandate@1b6d3586]
[Mandate@4554617c, Mandate@74a14482, Mandate@1540e19d, Mandate@677327b6, Mandate@14ae5a5]
[Mandate@7f31245a, Mandate@6d6f6e28, Mandate@135fbaa4, Mandate@45ee12a7, Mandate@330bedb4, Mandate@2503dbd3, Mandate@4b67cf4d]  sorry for the lack of specifics

Comment: Your class `Mandate` doesn't override `toString()`. Is `s.results` an instance of `Mandate`?

Comment: the mandate class is used to represent the name and its place within the list I am using.  the class looks like this.  'class Mandate{
  public String candidate;
  public String party;
  public int vote;
  public Mandate(String candidate,String party, int vote){
   this.candidate = candidate;
   this.party = party;
   this.vote = vote;' how would i override the toString()?

Comment: @bdg09715 Please edit the question (don't post code in the comments). What do you want it to look like when you print a `Mandate`?

Comment: I am looking to return the list of mandates as a number, each mandate represents a count of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer.parseInt("123")` to convert a `String` (`"123"`) to an `Integer` (`123`).

What `String` are you trying to convert though ?

Let me know if it works (or not)
Happy coding :) -Charlie

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to an int:

```
String s = "5";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Your question is a bit confusing, so if this isn't what you're looking for, let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.